# Condition number for 2-norm?

Tags: numerical-methods

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4SCy.png)

Can anyone tell me if I have made right thoughts in the attached task?
To solve the system I just solve $x=A^{-1}b$. To find the 2-norm of matrix $A$ I use the "power method", because the 2-norm for a normal matrix like matrix $A$ is the largest eigenvalue for $A$?

I have found a formula for condition number for 2-norm of a normal matrix: 
$$
\mathrm{cond}(A)=\frac{\mathrm{eigenvalue}_\max(A)}{\mathrm{eigenvalue}_\min(A)}
$$
To find $\mathrm{eigenvalue}_\min(A)$, I just find the eigenvalue for $A^{-1}$ with "inverse power method"?
Have I understood it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The inverse power method used on $A$ computes $\mathrm{eigenvalue}_\min(A)$. But remember that $A$ should be the input and not $A^{-1}$.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{eigenvalue}_\max(A)}{\mathrm{eigenvalue}_\min(A)}
= \mathrm{eigenvalue}_\max(A)\cdot \mathrm{eigenvalue}_\max(A^{-1})
= \Vert A\Vert_2 \cdot \Vert A^{-1}\Vert_2
=: \kappa(A)
$$
so you formula is correct. The second equality is true when $A$ is normal.

Comment: I don't understand. If it correct that eigenvalue_min(A)=eigenvalue_max(A^-1) then we must have:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{eigenvalue}_\max(A)}{\mathrm{eigenvalue}_\min(A)}
= \mathrm{eigenvalue}_\max(A)\ / \mathrm{eigenvalue}_\max(A^{-1})
= \Vert A\Vert_2 / \Vert A^{-1}\Vert_2
=: \kappa(A)
$$?

Comment: $\mathrm{eigenvalue}_\min(A) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{eigenvalue}_\max(A^{-1})}$

Comment: Thank you it makes sense. But how are the solutions for the equation system related to the condition-number? I have found that x=(2,0) for b=(2,2) and x=(1,1) for b=(2,2.001) and I have now found that cond(A)=4003.00075. I can't see anything relatable?

Comment: A large condition number means that even a small change in the b-vector can mean a large change in the solution vector. More precisely, the relative difference in x can be up to kappa times the relative difference in b.